# How to send message or notification from one tablet to another tablet in an android appication

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to send a message or notification from one tablet to another tablet in android appication? Both users are using the same application. Using wifi we give notice one user to another user.

Thanks

Comment: this is an exact duplicate of another questions that showed up a few minutes earlier from a different user.

Comment: Can you give the link @hooray, I'll close this as an exact dupe

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6371670/sending-notification-between-android-devices> ... they aren't exact duplicates because this one mentions tablets, but the answers will be the same.