# sending notification between Android devices

Tags: android, messaging

I have App "A" in android device "A" and i have the App "A" in android device "B" . Is it possible for me to send the notifications between the devices through WIFI??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's a variety of ways to do this, but ultimately it all boils down to have an app running on the second device that receives some trigger to show a notification.

Some examples....

You can have an app with a open server socket on device b and then discover and connect to it to send a message that triggers a notification over TCP/IP. http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/ can help with discovery.

If they both have a network connection, you can build something on the App Engine to send a C2DM message to device B, and then upon receiving that message trigger a notification.